# Keras TimeDistributed input_shape mismatch

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I'm trying to build a model with the TimeDistributed Dense layer, but I still get this error.

```
ValueError: `TimeDistributed` Layer should be passed an `input_shape` with at least 3 dimensions, received: (None, 16)
```

Am I missing something? The data has a format like the one provided in the snippet below. The model is simplified, but the error is the same.

```py
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import LSTM, TimeDistributed, Dense
import numpy as np


data = np.random.random((100, 10, 32))
labels = np.random.randint(2, size=(100, 10, 1))

model = Sequential()

model.add(LSTM(16, input_shape=(10, 32)))
model.add(TimeDistributed(Dense(10, activation='sigmoid')))

model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam')
model.fit(data, labels, epochs=10, batch_size=32)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing the number of units in your output layer to 1 and using `return_sequences=True` in your `LSTM` layer to get an output space for each timestep:

```
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import LSTM, TimeDistributed, Dense
import numpy as np


data = np.random.random((100, 10, 32))
labels = np.random.randint(2, size=(100, 10, 1))

model = Sequential()

model.add(LSTM(16, input_shape=(10, 32), return_sequences=True))
model.add(TimeDistributed(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')))

model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam')
model.fit(data, labels, epochs=10, batch_size=32)
```